# What does this function do (how does it work)?

Tags: python

```
def multi_search(pat_file : open, text_file : open) -> {str:[int]}:
    answer = {(p.rstrip(),re.compile(p.rstrip())):[] for p in pat_file}
    for num,line in enumerate(text_file,1):
        line = line.rstrip()
        for (p,c),lines in answer.items():
            if c.search(line) != None:
                lines.append(num)
    return {p:l for (p,c),l in answer.items()}
```

[image]

the function takes two lists, but I am not sure what the function returns, the two lists are shown in the picture.

Can someone explain to me that what does this function do and how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

For each pattern in the first file, the function finds all the line numbers in the second file containing the given pattern. A dictionary is returned, containing `pattern --> list of line numbers`.